# How can a dynamically created SVG polygon access an onClick function in a React functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg, onclick

Below is the problematic code in question. It works except for `polygon.setAttribute("onclick", "logMe(this)");` line which throws the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: logMe is not defined at SVGRectElement.onclick ()`

My question is: how can I get a click on this polygon to fire `logMe()`, or quite frankly any bespoke function?

Thank you for reading.

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { selectHotspotsBySceneIndex, ceneIndexselectImageMapBySceneIndex } from "../../redux/product/product.selectors";

import "./image-map.styles.scss";

const ImageMap = ({ hotspot, imageMap }) => {

    const init = () => {
        let loadingImage = document.getElementById("loadingImage");
        loadingImage.style.display = "none";
        loadingImage.addEventListener("load", loadImage);
        loadingImage.src = imageMap.url;
    };

    const loadImage = () => {
        let loadingImage = document.getElementById("loadingImage");
        loadingImage.removeEventListener("load", loadImage);
        polygon = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
        polygon.setAttribute("x", hotspot.points.x);
        polygon.setAttribute("y", hotspot.points.y);
        polygon.setAttribute("width", hotspot.points.width);
        polygon.setAttribute("height", hotspot.points.height);
        polygon.setAttribute("id", hotspot.id);
        polygon.setAttribute("class", "hotspotable");
        polygon.setAttribute("onclick", "logMe(this)");
        group.appendChild(polygon);
    };

    const logMe = polygon => {
        console.log("Hello, I am a", polygon);
    };
    
    return (
        <div>
            <svg id="svg-view-box" onLoad={init}>
                <image id="svgImage" width="100" height="100" href={imageMap.url} />
                <g id="group" />
            </svg>
            <img id="loadingImage" alt="" />
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    hotspots: selectHotspotsBySceneIndex(ownProps.sceneIndex)(state),
    imageMap: ceneIndexselectImageMapBySceneIndex(ownProps.sceneIndex)(state)
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ImageMap);
```

Comment: logme is internal method of ImageMap it is not accessible outside. Once rendering is done. Your polygon has access to window but not ImageMap.

Comment: magic, thanks deepak, assigning the func to window worked